# reflection calling 2 methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, reflection

I'm trying to do something like this but with reflection:

```
var ss1= method1(param).method2();
```

I know how to invoke the first method but I don't know how to invoke the second one.

method 1 returns an object

method 2 is the GetAwaiter method(in my particular case)

```
 MethodInfo mi = typeof(type).GetMethod("method1");
        Type tt = typeof(type);
        ParameterInfo[] param = mi.GetParameters();

        object[] param = new object[] { //some code  };
        object mm= mi.Invoke(this, param);
        MethodInfo mi2 = typeof(type).GetMethod("GetAwaiter");
        var ss1= mi2.Invoke(mm,null);
```

on the last line i get an error: "object does not match target type"

Comment: Are both methods in the same type? Otherwise you'd need to use the type returned by the first method to get method2:  MethodInfo mi2 = mm.GetType().GetMethod("GetAwaiter");

Comment: It would be easier if you gave your two methods (method1 + method2) definitions (declaration,  with return type params)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more or less correct, but that exception is telling you that mm is not what you think it is. The type returned by your method1 is not the same as the type you have specified in the .GetMethod("GetAwaiter") line.

A safer bet would be to replace typeof(type) with mm.GetType().GetMethod("GetAwaiter"). I suspect that will actually return null, since mm.GetType() doesn't seem to be what you expect, but without seeing more code (in particular, what 'type' is and where the "method1" and "GetAwaiter" methods are actually declared) it's hard to give you much more guidance.

Comment: i can't put the whole code because is just too big. Indeed mm.GetType().GetMethod("GetAwaiter") is null

Comment: Can you give us just the method signature of the "method1" method, and tell us what class "GetAwaiter" is declared in? Those both need to be the same type for this code to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on this line

```
MethodInfo mi2 = typeof(type).GetMethod("GetAwaiter");
```

mm object has a different type, so you get an exception. Change the line to

```
MethodInfo mi2 = mm.GetType().GetMethod("GetAwaiter");
```

as Tim suggests.

It's better to use the Type.InvokeMember method since it's shorter and helps avoid errors like this. For example:

```
object mResult = this.GetType ().InvokeMember ("method1", 
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance, null, this, 
    new object[] { /* parameters here */ });
object awaiter = mResult.GetType ().InvokeMember ("GetAwaiter",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance, null, mResult, null);
```